# Abrir uma outra atividade silenciosamente

Tags: java, android

É o seguinte; adicionei um botão para abrir uma atividade de um outro app. É possível abrir só que silenciosamente, ou seja, anônimo, invisível, minimizado, ou melhor, sem o usuário perceber!?

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.exemplo.pacote.MainActivity");
        startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: No qual sentido estaria "aberto", então? O outro app é seu?

Comment: Olá amigo, então, o sentido "aberto", seria fazendo um processo só que em segundo plano. Ele estaria "aberto" em segundo plano. Não, o outro app não é meu.

Comment: Ola amigo, recomendo a leitura sobre services e uma lida aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292779/create-new-intent-in-background

Answer (score 1):

Facilmente não conheço uma forma de fazer isso. 
Como o outro app não é seu, por padrão não há como controlar isso, senão seria um problema de segurança. Imagine eu fazer um aplicativo que abra todos do seu aparelho até travar em background?